# Count rows from multiple tables with similar names

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, table, count, row

I want to have 2 columns: Table Name and Row Count

When I run this, I get 12 table names in my database. How do I then count the rows in each one without having to union 12 count queries together:

```
SELECT T.name FROM sys.tables t
WHERE name LIKE '%20170101%'
```

Comment: Maybe [Query to list number of records in each table in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443704/query-to-list-number-of-records-in-each-table-in-a-database) will help.

Answer (score 0):

Did some more research....I guess these details are already stored in a catalog view that you can just query:

```
SELECT      T.name TableName,i.Rows NumberOfRows
FROM        sys.tables T
JOIN        sys.sysindexes I ON T.OBJECT_ID = I.ID
WHERE       indid IN (0,1)
AND         t.name LIKE '%20170101%'
ORDER BY    i.Rows DESC,T.name
```

Comment: How does this work out when you have multiple indexes on the same table? What if all of the indexes are filtered indexes (I imagine the row count would be incorrect then)? I would also imagine if you had a heap table (a table with no indexes) that table would get filtered out of this query too.

Comment: @J.D.: I think the `indid IN (0,1)` filter makes sure that for each table either the heap or the clustered index is checked.  AFAIK, the ID of 0 always refers to a heap and 1 to a clustered index.

Comment: sys.sysindexes should not be used since it is a compatibility view for sql server **2000**. And unlike the link in the first comment, the value of i.Rows should be considered as more of an estimate since that column is not updated in real-time

Comment: This also doesn't take into account partitioned tables, you need to `SUM` by `t.object_id`